# Ruby on Rails - Seeding big data (over 2.7M) record to production database

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

In my application I have a `City` model. I have a `sql` file that contains all the cities in the world *(its over 2.7M)* & I need to seed all of them to my production server.

I know usually I could do this in `seeds.rb`:

```
cities = City.create([

{id: 1, name: 'Bombuflat',  state_id: 1},
{id: 2, name: 'Garacharma',  state_id: 1},
{id: 3, name: 'Port Blair',  state_id: 1},
// Other cities
])
```

But since this is a big data to seed, it will take really long time to add `id`, `name`, `state_id` on each line.

Right now my `cities.sql` has a array of cities like:

```
//id, state_id, name
(1, 1, 'Aixàs'),
(2, 1, 'Aixirivali'),
(3, 1, 'Aixirivall')
```

What is the best way to do this so I don't need to add `id`, `name`, `state_id` to each line and maybe use the array I already have.

Comment: Why don't you dump the SQL into your production DB instead of doing it through Rails?

Comment: Honestly I don't think this amount of data should be inserted with ActiveRecord for seeding purposes. Use a tool to bulk insert the data in to the database. `LOAD DATA INFILE` in MySQL can do that in a few seconds with a modestly powered database.

Comment: @Bustikiller Because in my production I use postgresql

Comment: @vcsjones any tool for postgresql

Comment: The solution is agnostic of the database you are using, that is, all database management systems have tools to import data regardless of the application they have built on them.

Comment: @Bustikiller Thanks. Im not familiar with agnostic of the database. Could you please give me a example?

Comment: Try to use CSV and `PostgreSQL's COPY`. It *is* for fast data dump/load.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Could you please give a example in answer so I can understand and for future guys with same issue. Appreciate it

Comment: @FriendofAfriend You should do some research first -- I found this with the first Google search https://github.com/diogob/postgres-copy

Comment: @FriendofAfriend Yes, I agree with David - find `COPY` documentation is easy. I did an answer just because you accepted worst one - don't even try to insert 2.7M rows with AR and without transaction

Answer (score 2):

Most of big DBMS extend SQL with command for bulk seeding. [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) is `PostgreSQL` one. `COPY` is much faster than `INSERT`.

So, you need to have `CSV` file with headers corresponding to column names (*id, name, stated_id*). You can obtain it from another PostgreSQL DB with `COPY` also.

Call it `cities.csv` and place it in `db` folder. Then your `seeds.rb` might look like:

```
csv_path = Rails.root.join('db', 'cities.csv')
copy_clause = "COPY cities FROM '#{csv_path}' WITH(FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(copy_clause)
```

Then run `rake db:seed`.

Answer (score 0):

For example do something like this:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection


  sql = File.read('db/MySQL.sql')
  statements = sql.split(/;$/)
  statements.pop

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    statements.each do |statement|
      connection.execute(statement)
    end
  end
end
```